# Simplify jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, syntax, selector, simplify

I have a selector, "`td > a.leftmenuitem:last, div > a.leftmenuitem:last`", and I'd like to simplify it a little. I've tried "`* > a.leftmenuitem:last`", "`td, div > a.leftmenuitem:last`", and "`(td, div) > a.leftmenuitem:last`", none of which work the way the first selector does. Is this kind of thing just not possible in the selector syntax without making a separate selector for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simplify:

```
td > a.leftmenuitem:last, div > a.leftmenuitem:last
```

without there being something in common so you can select all relevant td and div elements with one expression. For example if they both had class blah you could do:

```
.blah > a.leftmenuitem:last
```

**But do not use this kind of expression if you can avoid it.** Class selectors are slow (compared to ID and tag selectors).

Is there something wrong with just?

```
a.leftmenuitem:last
```

?

By the way, are you certain `:last` is the correct choice? A lot of people mistakenly using it, mistaking it for `:last-child`. `:last` will only match one element, the last matching element found on the page.

Comment: Ah yes! Of course :last-child works perfectly. I was wondering why just using a.leftmenuitem:last didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is bigger, sometimes is faster. When you use ***** instead of **td**, your query is much slower.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can simplify it. I'd instead opt towards giving the links you're interested in a unique class, so that you can simply do `"a.<my-unique-class>:last"`. That way jquery can simply scan all matching `<a>` tags without worrying about their parent being a `<td>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is simple enough.  If you wanted to simplify it, you could do something like:

```
$('a.leftmenuitem:last').parent().doWhateverYouWereGoingToDo();
```

I doubt this would result in faster execution times, however.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just confused, but if

```
* > a.leftmenuitem:last
```

would work for you, then why not go with

```
a.leftmenuitem:last
```

instead?

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're using is

```
Parent > Child
```

match all child elements specified by `Child`  of elements specified by `Parent`. Unless you are using `<a>` elements elsewhere in the page that are not children of `<div>` and `<td>` elements, why not just use

```
$('a.leftmenuitem:last')
```

Am I missing something?